# If I don't use my xbox that day, will it still count as a day gone from my live membership?

Tags: xbox-360

I'm deciding on if I should buy an xbox 360 but the live memberships cost a lot. If I don't use my xbox at all on a certain day, will a day still be gone from my live membership?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, even if you don't use your xbox, your subscription time will go down.

Comment: It's worth noting that a subscription doesn't "go down." It just expires on a set date. There's no set amount of time that you have on it unless you consider the time between now and when your subscription is up as a "set time."

Comment: Thank you so much. It helps a lot. Do you think getting an xbox is worth it with all the games and memberships?

Comment: @KylieVandewege I'd just build a pc.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this, what does that mean?

Comment: @KylieVandewege Xbox 360 is a rather old console. It was released on 2005 and is discontinued as of 2016. I recommend just building a new PC, by buying parts and combining them. There are some good part lists [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PCMasterRace/wiki/builds).

Comment: the xbox 360 is not discontinued, its still selling in amazon and like best buy

Comment: @KylieVandewege yes, [but they stopped making new ones and they're only selling the ones on existing inventory](http://news.xbox.com/2016/04/20/xbox-360-celebrating-10-years/)

Comment: @KylieVandewege Although the 360 has been replaced by the One, many people still play 360 games online. You should still be able to find plenty of people to play with, and there are many many games in the catalog available for you to buy. Get it for a month and see if you like it. If you do, get it for the a full year, as it's a good discount. Sometimes you can find discounted memberships from third-party dealers online.

Answer (score 1):

The Xbox live membership expires on a certain day always. No matter if you are using your Xbox or not.

Furthermore the membership will be refreshed automatically, if you do not unsubscribe or cancel the automatic refreshing.

One more hint, if the membership is very pricey for you, consider to options: Only get a one month subscription, when you really know you will play enough. Or you can buy a full or half year to get a discount.